# Map array of locales and change each locale to language name

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization

Using Next.js, I'm getting the current locale and all available locales for a language selection menu:

```
const {cl, al} = useContext(LangContext);
// cl = "en-US"
// al = ["en-US", "de-DE"]
```

I wrote this function to return the full language name:

```
const clAlias = ()=> {
    if (cl === "en-US") { return "English" };
    if (cl === "de-DE") { return "Deutsch" };
}
```

Now I want to map `al` , but instead of having `["en-US", "de-DE"]` I want to have `["English", "Deutsch"]`. It not only looks better but also makes it easier for the user to select their language.
What would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an object.

```js
const clAlias = {
  "en-US": "English",
  "de-DE": "Deutsch"
}
//...
al.map(x => clAlias[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method. It return new array without change `al`

And don't forget add arguments in `clAlias()` like  `clAlias(cl)`

```js
const al = ["en-US", "de-DE"];
const clAlias = (cl) => {
  if (cl === "en-US") {
    return "English";
  }
  if (cl === "de-DE") {
    return "Deutsch";
  }
};

const answer = Array.from(al, (e) => clAlias(e));
console.log(answer);
```